# web3js get all properties of contract in one promise

Tags: solidity, web3js, factory

I'm implementing an app with a Factory design pattern. My Factory is creating instances of myContract, that I load thanks to myContract.at(address) like below:

```
this.myContract = TruffleContract(Contract)
this.myContract .setProvider(this.web3Provider)
this.myContractABI = this.web3.eth.contract(this.leaseContract.abi.abi);
this.myContractInstance = this.myContract.at(leaseAddress)
```

This is working fine! I can then get my properties from a promise:

```
this.myContractInstance.propertyContract().then((propertyContract) => {
          this.setState({ property = propertyContract })       
        })
```

This works fine!

But the problem is that I've 15 properties in my smart contract. 
If I have to get them one by one I'm thinking it's ugly code and it's not really efficient?

Can I get a promise on the whole smart contract and get all my properties in one promise ? 
Something like this maybe:

```
this.myContract.at(leaseAddress).then((contractInstance) => {

  this.setState({ propertyA = contractInstance.propertyA })
  this.setState({ propertyB = contractInstance.propertyA })
  this.setState({ propertyC = contractInstance.propertyA })
  etc...
})
```

I think you get the idea :) Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). That doesn't avoid listing all the properties you want to fetch, but it gives them all back to you in a single callback.

Comment: You could create a function that finds all the function in the ABI that are declared `view`. Then, you could have it call all those functions using `Promise.all` and store the results in an object. I'd only do this if it's likely to be used many times, though.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems it's something that happens all the time no? Being able to store all the fields from a smart contract into react states? Seems complicated. I was using a struct before, and returning directly the struct in the promise was simple. However, struct in solidity is limited to 9 variables, which is not enough. 
I feel like something simpler should be used, or am I missing something? if I have Contract A with 20 public uint, how do I get them all in one call? Having 20 calls seems not efficient, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve multiple contract properties in a single call?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/99234/how-to-retrieve-multiple-contract-properties-in-a-single-call)