Read data from multiple contracts using wagmi and react
I have to read some data about a list of contracts having same abi, I've been using useReadContracts from wagmi but that only gives the information about 1 contract at a time. I tried fetching the data in a loop but whenever I call my custom hook inside a useEffect hook, I get the invalid hook call error, if I don't use a useEffect, then the data fetching is an infinite process.
I'm wondering if there exists a clean and robust solution for reading data from multiple contracts in one go.

You'd use something like multi-call, and you can make multiple calls in 1 API call. I'd give you a direct answer but I'd have to do some testing to implement it in wagmi. Would love to see an example here after you get it sorted. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/99234/how-to-retrieve-multiple-contract-properties-in-a-single-call

@PatrickCollins Thankyou, multi-call solved the problem beautifully, I posted an example below.

As Patrick Collins suggested in the comment, multi-call is the way to go!
Here's a code snippet from my working solution:
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ResABI, RES_ADDRESS } from "@/constants";
import { Abi, Address } from "viem";
import { multicall } from "@wagmi/core";
import { wagmiConfig } from "@/config";

.
.
.

const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
const [data, setData] = useState<TResData[]>([]);

const resContracts = addresses.map(
    (address) =>
      ({
        address: RES_ADDRESS,
        abi: ResABI as Abi,
        functionName: "getResMethod",
        args: [address],
      }) as const,
  );

useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const resMethods = (await multicall(wagmiConfig, {
        allowFailure: false,
        contracts: [...resContracts],
      }));

      return resMethods.map((resmethod, index) => ({
        method: resMethod,
      }));
    };

    try {
      getData().then((_data) => setData(_data));
    } catch (e) {
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }, []);

.
.
.

Here's the reference from docs.
